# Check count of repeated digits or characters in Hive column

Tags: python, pandas, hive, hql

I have a column with numbers in hive. I want to have the count of those rows where digits are repeated and this can be a case for a column of characters also.

Eg-[image: Example column]

Output should be 6.

I tried using reverse function of hive but it also gives palindrome numbers.
Sample code which i tried -

```
select sum(case when Number = reverse(Number) then 1 else 0 end) as counts
from table
where Number is not null
```

Comment: I am unaware of hiveql. Shall I provide solution in Oracle then may be you can create equivalent query in hiveql

Comment: Yeah sure, it will be good. But the problem is with hive which is not as versatile as mysql or oracle

Comment: Please describe how "6" is calculated.  I see seven numbers that have pairs of duplicated digits.

Comment: @GordonLinoff even a single digit should be considered as repeated. And repeated digits can be odd or even in length.

Comment: Output is 6 because repeated digits should be standalone such as - 1,2222,33,4444,999999,55.
Also number of digits can be odd or even in length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(distinct Number) as dist_numbers
from table
where trim(number) rlike ^0+$|^1+$|^2+$|^3+$|^4+$|^5+$|^6+$|^7+$|^8+$|^9+$;
```

This is a temporary but cumbersome approach.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to know if all digits appear a multiple of 2 times.

One rather painful method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where ( length(number) - length(replace(number, '0', '')) ) % 2 = 0 and
      ( length(number) - length(replace(number, '1', '')) ) % 2 = 0 and
      . . .
      ( length(number) - length(replace(number, '9', '')) ) % 2 = 0
```

Comment: Repeated digits can be odd or even in length, this is why i tried using "reverse" but it counts palindrome numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Use hive repeat function**

```
with myTable as (
  select 1 Number union
  select 2222 Number union
  select 1221 Number union
  select 33 Number union
  select 4444 Number union
  select 12 Number union
  select 100 Number union
  select 999999 Number union
  select 55 Number union
  select 40 Number 
) -- test data 

select Number from myTable
where Number = repeat(substr(Number,1,1),length(Number))
;
+---------+--+
| number  |
+---------+--+
| 1       |
| 33      |
| 55      |
| 2222    |
| 4444    |
| 999999  |
+---------+--+
6 rows selected
```

**2. Use explode function**

```
with myTable as (
  select 1 Number union
  select 2222 Number union
  select 1221 Number union
  select 33 Number union
  select 4444 Number union
  select 12 Number union
  select 100 Number union
  select 999999 Number union
  select 55 Number union
  select 40 Number
)  -- test data

select Number from (
  select Number, count(Number) as cnt
  from (
    select distinct Number, s.Chars from myTable 
    lateral view explode(split(Number,'')) s as Chars
  ) t
  where Chars != ""
  group by Number
) t 
where cnt = 1
;
```